# How to find equation for 11 independent variables that predicts a single outcome?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I don't know a lot of statistics so I don't even know what search terms to use...

I have a data set that includes 11 independent variables. All quantifiable, like age, height, weight, IQ, etc. that you would use for people. Then I have one dependent variable, also quantifiable, let's say income.

I'm searching for an equation to bring my 11 variables together, e.g.:

Income = x1*a + x2*b + x3*c...

Or better yet:

Income = f(x1) + f(x2) + f(x3) ...

Question 1:

What is the methodology to finding this equation called?

Obviously the goal is finding the best equation to use to predict income in this example based on 11 quantifiable characteristics. I'd also like the solution to consider the cases where the coefficients could be zero (i.e. telling me that certain predictors are best left out/ignored).

Question 2:

How do I determine how good my equation is? In other words, if I have a crappy data set, the equation might be pretty crappy. But then if I improve the data set, the new equation would be better. How do I measure the accuracy or predictive power of my equation? In other words, how do I answer the question quantifiable "how well does my equation predict income? how close does it get?"

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methodology is called [regression analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis).  You can measure predictive power via the [coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination).